How to close popup manually in vim
I'm having bad time closing popups shown in the pictures below. I can't find any information in the Vim and coc-nvim help documentation, nor could I find help on the internet.
These windows don't disappear on their own.
I use coc-nvim. These popups appear when i use command :CocCommand document.checkBuffer.


